# Using GN build system, how to set cflag to specific source file in a target

Tags: flutter, chromium, gn

I use 'sources = []' to add several source files to a target.
And according to this thread https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/tpZ0q6cDTQk, I can use 'config += or -=' to change compiler flags.
But the flags apply to all sources.

How can I add/remove a cflag and apply to one of the source files?

Comment: That same page has answer to your question. Use `source_set`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I create a static target for the specific source file and set unique cflag for it.